# Javascript Unexpected run order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery / javascript code below. It ask user for location permission, and then outputs a URL string with latitude appended at the end.

I put 3 console.log statemnets to highlight problem, with current outputs I get.

Expected Debug Values (in order)

> 1_lat =95.555555
>
> 2_lat =95.555555
>
> 3_https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?&lat=95.555555

Actual Debug Values: (in order)

> 2_
>
> 3_https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?&
>
> 1_lat =95.555555

```
var curLat ='';
var curLon ='';
var weatherAPI='';

$(document).ready(function(){

  if (navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
      curLat = "lat=" + position.coords.latitude;
      console.log("1_", curLat);
    });
  } 

  weatherAPI = getURL(curLat);
  console.log("3_", weatherAPI);
});

function getURL(lat){
  console.log("2_", lat);
  var url =  "https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?";
  url = url + "&" + lat;
  return url;
}
```

I must not be understanding something with how javascript is loading and how jQuery document.ready.function is affecting the results.

Answer (score 1):

`navigator.geolocation` is async. So you have to wait for the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` callback function before you can process the `lat` and `lng`

You can do something like this:

```
var curLat ='';
var curLon ='';
var weatherAPI='';

$(document).ready(function(){

  if (navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
      curLat = "lat=" + position.coords.latitude;
      console.log("1_", curLat);
      weatherAPI = getURL(curLat);
      console.log("3_", weatherAPI);
    });
  } 
});

function getURL(lat){
  console.log("2_", lat);
  var url =  "https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?";
  url = url + "&" + lat;
  return url;
}
```

This will result to:

```
1_ lat=1.xxx 
2_ lat=1.xxx 
3_ https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?&lat=1.xxx
```

Comment: how would one find out navigator.geolocation is async?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: isn't javascript single threaded and synchronous by default, how would you know using navigator.geolocation is async?

Comment: How would I know? Besides, you'll be able to know that on its behavior, there are a lot of documents online saying that.